# How to update listview from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

First of all sorry if its a duplicate because i am asking it because unable to understand anything from other questions or i can say i am not able it to implement in my case.
Actually i stuck to a situation where i want to update my `ListView` with updated one from network in `AsyncTask` but now how to implement it, don't know i tried few thing but not able to make it work. Please anyone explain me in detail how to do it, Here is my code for activity and Async class

```
    package app.balaji.sid.listapp;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;
    import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPFile;


    public class ListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        ListView lv;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
            lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            String[] values = new String[] { "Item 1",
                    "Item 2",
                    "Item 3 ",
                    "Item 4",
                    "Item 5",
                    "Item 6",
                    "Item 7",
                    "Item 8"
            };
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            new ListFetcher().execute();


        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        protected class ListFetcher extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
            String sid;


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String user = "user";
                String pass="password";
                String host="204.236.238.164";

                FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

                try {

                    client.connect(host,21);
                    client.login(user, pass);
                    client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
                    client.changeDirectory("/");

                    FTPFile[] files = client.list();
                    String[] fileNames = new String[files.length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                    {
                        fileNames[i] = files[i].getName();
                        String logVariable=fileNames[i];
                        Log.v(sid, logVariable);     // Here i am able to see list in log
                    }

                   }catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Log.v(sid,e.toString());
                }





                return sid;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute()
            {

    //i think list should be updated from here but don't know how to do it correctly
    // i just know i can update my listview by creating a new adapter and assign it to listview but don't know how
// also i am not able to get the fileNames array here

            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: A: Create an inheriting class which extends AsyncTask and let it implement an Interface which MainActivity also implements and call it on on post. B:Provide a weak reference to Activity inside your derivate and pass the Activity reference to the derivate in order to call a public method Of Activity OR call runOnUiThread from onPostExecute. Thogh i thought onPost runs already on ui thread.

Comment: @icbytes can you please answer it with some example as i am new to android so don't know too much

Comment: @icbytes it does run on the UI Thread so no need for `runOnUiThread()` there

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer if you posted links to dupes you've tried and explain what you don't understand. What is/isn't happening would also be helpful. But, from what I can see, you just need to pass your new `String` to `onPostExecute()` and update the list and `Adapter` there.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)  // get the String you are passing
{

    //i think list should be updated from here but don't know how to do it correctly
    // I agree. Let's try this
    if(result != null)  // let's make sure you got something
    {
         values.add(result);  // add the new String to your list
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // Hey, Adapter, we've got some new data

}
```

You need to change your `Array` to an `ArrayList` so the length can be dynamic. You will also want to make that and your `Adapter` member variables so the inner class can see them.

```
public class ListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView lv;

    // Declare them here
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    values.add("Item 1");
    values.add("Items 2");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, values);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    new ListFetcher().execute();
```

You aren't passing anything to your task but you want to return an Array

```
 @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {

 protected void onPostExecute(String[] result)
```

If you are returning a completely new set of values for your adapter then you can just update it with the new values. If you are just adding some values then you can iterate through them and add them to your `ArrayList` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` like shown above.

Comment: Thanks for making me understand about it but know app is force closing  Collections.addAll(values, result);  // 
                Log.v(sid,"working here");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // Here it stops

Comment: You're welcome. That's much more helpful than me just giving you working code. I don't know without knowing what the error is you are getting.

Comment: Here is the log which i got after stopping the app 09-02 00:05:08.221    4074-4074/app.balaji.sid.listapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.balaji.sid.listapp, PID: 4074
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at app.balaji.sid.listapp.ListActivity$ListFetcher.onPostExecute(ListActivity.java:116)
            at app.balaji.sid.listapp.ListActivity$ListFetcher.onPostExecute(ListActivity.java:61)

Comment: Something is `null` at line 116

Comment: line 116 is adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();, so what to do now??

Comment: What do you think is null there?

Comment: i think adapter is null and maybe not still not updated with the new data

Comment: It's definitely null. How/where are you initializing it now?

Comment: Here i did it :  Collections.addAll(values, result);

Comment: Where is that??? Pass an array to `onPostExecute()` and update yout adapter. That line you showed me does nothing with an adapter. You need something like you have with `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, values);`

Comment: I just followed you and added that and app stops closing but still not updating lisview, so i just thought i have to set it with adapter like lv.setAdapter(adapter); but when added this its starts closing again with some error related to relative layout

Comment: Then I would, again, need to know that error to help you

Comment: i just added lv.setAdapter(adapter); before                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 and i am getting this : 09-02 01:15:38.481  30262-30262/app.balaji.sid.listapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.balaji.sid.listapp, PID: 30262
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255) and many more but too long to post here

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60417/discussion-on-answer-by-codemagic-how-to-update-listview-from-asynctask).

Comment: @bluefeet thanks and I agree. If we could get somewhere with this then it wouldn't be a problem(shameless meta promotion)(http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255825/regarding-the-reputation-criteria-for-chatting/255828#255828)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem, so just thought i need to share it, so other who are facing the same problem can do it easily.

So first of all in my question i just declared my AsyncTask class with string parametres but actually i need to populate my ListView from here.

So what i did :

```
 protected class ListFetcher extends AsyncTask<ArrayList,ArrayList,ArrayList>{
        String sid;
        ArrayList list;



        @Override
        protected ArrayList doInBackground(ArrayList... params) {
 FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

            try {

                client.connect(host,21);
                client.login(user, pass);
                client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
                client.changeDirectory("/");

                FTPFile[] files = client.list();
                String[] fileNames = new String[files.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                {
                    fileNames[i] = files[i].getName();
 String logVariable=fileNames[i];
                    Log.v(sid, logVariable);
                    values.add(fileNames[i]);

                }

               }catch (Exception e)
            {

                Log.v(sid,e.toString());
            }





            return list;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList  result)//received result but didn't use it because in my case i don't need it instead of it i just updated my arraylist in doInbackground and updated my ui from here
        {


            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
            ListView listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);




        }
```

Comment: If you are setting your `Adapter` there then you shouldn't need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. That is for when you have already set it on the `ListView` and you update the list.